# Is IBM\HCL Domino Server FP 9.0.1 compatible with Windows Server 2016?

Tags: lotus-domino, ibm-domino

I googled this question before asking here and I can't find any there.

**Anyone here tried installing HCL\IBM Domino Server FP 9.0.1 using Windows Server 2016?**  Will it run without any problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Should work: https://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/new_features_nd901fp8.htm?opendocument&comments

Answer (score 0):

Here's an official compatibility list, which says Domino 9.0.1 FP10 is supported on Windows Server 2016:

https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0085697&sys_kb_id=cfc1b5a01b8da0d4534c4159cc4bcb5d

However, note that your question is more suited to https://serverfault.com, because the question's not about programming.